# How to insert value into uuid column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, text, casting, sql-update, uuid

I have a table with a `uuid` column, and some of the rows are missing the data. I need to insert data into this `uuid` column. The data is entered manually, so we are suffixing with other column data to differentiate, but it gives me an error.

```
UPDATE schema.table 
    SET uuid_column = CONCAT ('f7949f56-8840-5afa-8c6d-3b0f6e7f93e9', '-', id_column) 
WHERE id_column = '1234';
```

> Error: [42804] ERROR: column "uuid_column" is of type uuid but expression is of type text
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
>   Position: 45

I also tried

```
UPDATE schema.table 
   SET uuid_column = CONCAT ('f7949f56-8840-5afa-8c6d-3b0f6e7f93e9', '-', id_column)::uuid 
WHERE id_column = '1234';
```

> Error: [22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for uuid: "f7949f56-8840-5afa-8c6d-3b0f6e7f93e9-1234"

Comment: Well, you can't do what you are trying to do there. `f7949f56-8840-5afa-8c6d-3b0f6e7f93e9` is already a complete and valid UUID, you can't append anything to that value. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve with that? If you want to generate a UUID, [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) extension and use e.g. `uuid_generate_v4()`

Comment: I am trying to update missing uuid data. since we are adding it manually, we need something to differentiate between manually added and systematically added and that's why we are suffixing with id_column.

Comment: For that add something like a boolean column telling _uuid_column_ is  manually added. Another option is to change the column type `uuid` to `varchar` but that makes things just difficult elsewhere.

Comment: okay, so it looks like we cannot suffix or prefix anything while inserting into uuid column. Is that a correct statement?

I do not like the option to convert into varchar, that will create a mess.

Comment: Correct,  you cannot. As you cannot insert - say - `text` to `bigint` column. It is not anymore `uuid` as [rfc4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122)  specifies it.

Comment: I think pirho's suggestion to add a flag indicating if it's a manual ID is the proper way to go

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Comment: What we are going to do is, we are going to create v5 uuid which specifies if it's manually generated or systematically generated since our system generates uuid v4. so no additional flag column needed.

Comment: Any updates on this? I had a similar requirement where I wanted to change the value of a uuid column but it is not working by set myCol = 'guid-here' ...

Answer (score 2):

An UUID consists of 16 bytes, which you see displayed in hexadecimal notation.

You cannot have a UUID with fewer or more bytes.

I recommend using the type `bytea` if you really need to do such a thing.